# Problemas con String.format()

Tags: java

Estoy insertando datos desde una interfaz gráfica a una base de datos, pero `String.format()` no da formato bien los valores (altera el orden de los datos), mientras que si los asigno directamente no hay ningún problema:

```
// Este funciona perfecto:
String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("INSERT INTO Tienda (ID, Nombre, Cantidad, Unidad, Valor)" 
    + "VALUES (null, 'Papa', 3, 'kg', 800)", oProducto.getID(), oProducto.getNombre(), oProducto.getCantidad(), oProducto.getUnidad(), oProducto.getValor());
    
// como necesito que funcione:
//String strSentenciaInsert = String.format("INSERT INTO Tienda (ID, Nombre, Cantidad, Unidad, Valor)" 
//    + "VALUES (null, '%s', %d, '%s', %d)", oProducto.getID(), oProducto.getNombre(), oProducto.getCantidad(), oProducto.getUnidad(), oProducto.getValor());
    
objConexion.ejecutarSentenciaSQL(strSentenciaInsert);
try {
    ResultSet resultado = objConexion.consultaRegistros("SELECT * FROM Tienda");
        
    while (resultado.next()) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta rápida a tu pregunta es que no estás agregando los parámetros adecuados a los marcadores que has incluido en tu cadena.

Has usado `(null, '%s', %d, '%s', %d)"`, donde esperas cuatro parámetros (uno de ellos lo has forzado a `null`) y, sin embargo, le pasas cinco parámetros:

```
String strSentenciaInsert = String.format(
    "INSERT INTO Tienda (ID, Nombre, Cantidad, Unidad, Valor)" 
    + "VALUES (null, '%s', %d, '%s', %d)",
    oProducto.getID(), /* Se asignará a "Nombre" */
    oProducto.getNombre(), /* Se asignará a "Cantidad" */
    oProducto.getCantidad(), /* Se asignará a "Unidad" */
    oProducto.getUnidad(), /* Se asignará a "Valor" */
    oProducto.getValor() /* No se usará */
 );
```

Obviamente es probable que donde ponías `null` deberías haber puesto un `%d`.

---

### Nota importante

Tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

NUNCA debes concatenar cadenas de caracteres a una consulta SQL. En su lugar debes usar [consultas preparadas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) como te muestro a continuación:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("""
    INSERT INTO Tienda (ID, Nombre, Cantidad, Unidad, Valor)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
""");
/* Asignamos los valores a los marcadores */
statement.setInt(1, oProducto.getID());
statement.setString(2, oProducto.getNombre());
statement.setInt(3, oProducto.getCantidad());
statement.setString(4, oProducto.getUnidad());
statement.setInt(5, oProducto.getValor());
```

Aquí puedes consultar los tipos de datos que puedes asignar a cada marcador:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: Muchas gracias, excelente respuesta, me ha ayudado mucho.